# How to find the infimum of a function (Lagrangian Dual)

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

In optimisation, we form what is known as a primal problem, e.g. (5.5 from [Boyd and Vandenberghe](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf)) 
$$
\min_x \;\;x^\top x
$$ 
$$ s.t. \;\;\;Ax=b$$

In the example, the Lagrangian is: 
$$ x^\top x + \nu^\top(Ax-b) $$

Now, I understand we can find the dual problem by first identifying the dual function, which is defined:
$$
g(x) = \inf_x \mathcal{L(x,\lambda,\nu)}
$$

where $\mathcal{L} $ represents the Lagrangian, and $\lambda$ and $\nu$ are the respective Lagrangian multipliers for the inequality and equality constraints.

In the example, the Lagrangian is found by setting $\nabla_x \mathcal{L}$ to zero and solving for $x*$, which appears to work because the function is convex? So, my question(s):

- Is this the method to find the dual for convex functions in general? (i.e. one solves for $x*$ and substitutes into $\mathcal{L}$)
- What if $\nabla_x \mathcal{L}$ does not give a single solution? (e.g. quadratic with nonzero determinant)
- Is there a general way to find the infimum of the Lagrangian function? It is okay if this is general within e.g. linear or quadratic programming

Comment: What do you mean by "the Lagrangian is found at the stationary point"?

Comment: Apologies, poor phrasing. I meant find the x-value of the stationary point of the Lagrangian function.. but I realise that actually simply setting $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L} } {\partial x} = 0 $ isn't the same as finding the stationary point. However, that is the technique used in the example so consider my question augmented :)  - what is this technique and when can I use it? Is it the general technique or is there another?

Comment: $g$ is a function of $\lambda$ and $\nu$, not of $x$.  Finding the inf by setting $\nabla_{x} L(x,\lambda,\nu)=0$ is only applicable when $L$ is differentiable.  In the dual problem, you're interested in maximizing $g(\lambda,\nu)$, which depends only on the inf, not on any specific $x$ that attains the inf.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a little more sense. Assuming I've understood you can submit as an answer that one can find $g(\lambda,\nu)$ by setting $\nabla_x \mathcal{L}(x,\lambda,\nu) =0 $ for differentiable $\mathcal{L}$, although it would be helpful to explain how this works, and also any other approach to find $g(\lambda,\nu)$ when this doesn't hold. The other textbook examples just seem to be found 'by inspection'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the dual function $g$ is

$g(\lambda, \nu)=\inf_{x} L(x,\lambda,\nu)$

This is a function of $\lambda$ and $\nu$, not a function of $x$ (correcting a misstatement in the question.)  The dual problem is then

$\max_{\lambda>0,\nu} g(\lambda,\nu)$

There's no completely general approach to finding the inf of $L(x,\lambda,\nu)$, but in those cases where $L$ is differentiable and convex with respect to $x$, any $x$ with $\nabla_{x} L(x,\lambda,\nu)=0$ will attain the inf.  In cases where $L$ isn't differentiable with respect to $x$, you'll have to find some other way to determine the inf.

In practice, it is often the case that the inf is $-\infty$ for values of $\lambda$ and $\nu$ that don't satisfy some constraint.  This gives an implicit constraint on the values of $\lambda$ and $\nu$ that provide a useful lower bound on the optimal primal objective value.    Such a constraint is typically made explicit in the dual problem.

To answer your specific questions:

> Is this the method to find the dual for convex functions in general?
>   (i.e. one solves for x∗ and substitutes into L)

Yes.  For problems with linear equality constraints it's also possible to use the Fenchel conjugate to find the Lagrangian dual problem, but that's a bit more advanced.

> What if ∇xL does not give a single solution? (e.g. quadratic with
>   nonzero determinant)

It's irrelevant whether there are multiple $x$ values at which the inf is attained, since only the value of the inf matters in $g(\lambda,\nu)$.

> Is there a general way to find the infimum of the Lagrangian function?
>   It is okay if this is general within e.g. linear or quadratic
>   programming

Not really. We've already discussed the case where $L$ is differentiable with respect to $x$.